# is it possible to run an amp into the boss br-800?

Tags: electric-guitar

Instead of using the tones from the br-800 it's it possible to run a line 6 spider 4(IV) into the br-800? If so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I have a Boss BR-800 and I have discovered it can do many things that are not explained in the manual.

You can absolutely input the signal from your Line 6 Spider iv from the headphone out directly into the BR 800 and capture the effects applied to the signal.  There are several ways you can do this.  I have detailed the two methods I recommend below (depending on which cables you may have on hand or can find in stock).

**First method.**  Connect headphone out from Line 6 to the Line In jack on the back of the BR-800.  To do this you will need a 3.5mm Male TRS to 1/4in Male TRS Stereo Interconnect Patch Cable like this one **[3.5mm to 1/4 inch cable](http://www.musiciansfriend.com/accessories/hosa-3.5mm-male-trs-to-1-4in-male-trs-stereo-interconnect-patch-cable?cntry=us&source=3WWRWXGP&gclid=CKrcuZ7H18kCFYElgQodqYwMQw&kwid=productads-plaid%5E131989856427-sku%5EJ02161000001000@ADL4MF-adType%5EPLA-device%5Ec-adid%5E83738188347)**

Then select "Input Select" from the main menu and tap "enter" and scroll through the selections to select "Line In".  The default will be a stereo mode and two channels will be used for recording.  You can change the mode to mono.

**Second method.**  Connect headphone out from Line 6 to Input 4 on the back of the BR 800 using a 1/4 inch TRS interconnect cable like this one **[1/4 inch TRS Interconnect Cable](http://www.zzounds.com/item--HOSHSS?siid=134235)** OR using a Balanced 1/4 inch to XLR Male cable like this **[1/4 inch to SLR male](http://www.musiciansfriend.com/accessories/hosa-balanced-1-4-inch-trs-male-to-3-pin-xlr-male-cable?cntry=us&source=3WWRWXGP&gclid=CP7O6ebJ18kCFdcWgQodMhAK3w&kwid=productads-plaid%5E131989856427-sku%5EJ01827000001000@ADL4MF-adType%5EPLA-device%5Ec-adid%5E83738188347)**

Then select "Input Select" from the main menu and tap "enter" and scroll through the selections to select "Input 4".  The default will be a mono mode but you can change the mode to stereo.

There are other ways to accomplish your goal but these are probably the easiest and fastest.  You might try both methods to see if one gives you better results than the other but I think either will work fine.  Be sure to adjust the input sensitivity to keep the signal from distorting.

If you want to do a quick and dirty recording of the music played through the Line 6 - with no cables required to connect the Line 6 Amp to the BR-800 - you could always use the built in mics on the BR-800 using "Mic L/R" as the input and adjust the input sensitivity on the BR 800 and the volume on the Line 6 and record the sound that you hear from your amp.  Of course any other sound will be recorded as well so you will have to be sure your neighbors dog is not barking.

Answer (score 0):

nice to have located this chat or page etc :) I have and use a Marshall tube amplifier with no additional effects. Is it possible for me to go from input amplifier to Br-800 headphones, then and then try and find my way further, from there?

In advance ; Have one on me :)

Comment: Welcome to Music.SE! This is actually a new question instead of an answer; you might want to ask a new question so that more people will see it. http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/ask